# Anychart, how to add event listener to a donut segment?

Tags: anychart

Anybody who knows how to add an event listener to a donut segment drawn on a stage in Anychart?

I tried the following code, but it didn't work (see the jsfiddle).

```
stage = acgraph.create("container");
donut = acgraph.vector.primitives.donut(stage,200,200,50,100, 0, 60);   

donut.listen("click",function() 
{
alert("Clicked!")   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncacampo/3a7hvbmt/

Answer (score 0):

to add an event listener to a donut segment we have to place this donut on a layer and add the listener exactly to this layer.

```
stage = acgraph.create("container");

var layer = stage.layer();

//now the fill of donut is absolutely transparent, but the color is black
layer.donut(200,200,50,100, 0, 60).fill("#fff", 0);

layer.listen('click', function() {
alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Also *fill()* setting is very important here. Without *fill()* method listener will react only on click on contour of donut. *Fill()* provides click reaction inside the segment. You can set any color and opacity (from 0 to 1).

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3a7hvbmt/1/)